# Updating my app from custom apk downloaded from my own server

Tags: android, upgrade, kiosk

I'm trying to upgrade my app after downloading a custom apk from my server using this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(i);
```

App installs correctly but the problem is that after installation it shows a prompt with Done/Open buttons. I want to open the app right after installation without showing this Done/Open prompt since its a kiosk app. If user presses Done button app wont open and it would be out of kiosk mode.

I have tried using `PackageReceiver` and `startActivityForResult` approaches but they don't work as i'm installing apk for my own app so it closes.

Any way to just open the newly installed apk right after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Add to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

And add the code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String fileStr = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp";
            File file = new File(fileStr, "app.apk");
            Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Comment: I have tried adding this permission to manifest, this doesn't help, package manager prompt with Done/Open still shows